# Forward outgoing(OUTLINKS) URL's to redirecting webpage using php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, hyperlink

I am building a website in which there are many outgoing URL's (i.e OUTLINKS). I want to track the OUTLINKS and forward them to a webpage which is used for forwarding and counting.

example: in html i have

```
<a href="http://otherwebsite.com">other website</a>
```

I want the page get redirected to `http://mywebsite.com/somefolder/url?target=http://otherwebsite.com`.

How can I acheive forwarding every OUTLINKS to my webpage, either using .htaccess or php

thanks in advance

Comment: I would use ajax to update the count when the link is clicked... redirecting them through some sort of a broker page seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, the first being the most viable option, the second may have issues with some visitors...

1. In your HTML (or server side scripting), make your links go to the redirect script
2. Use javascript/jquery to change all the external links to prepend the redirect path

Comment: thanks Rob, 
Did you mean, using {<a href="http://mywebsite.com/somefolder/url?target=http://otherwebsite.com">other website</a>}, I was actually looking for some server side scripting to do it automatically.

Comment: I guess you could write something that checks for external links. maybe during the output buffering or a function that does it.. such as `<?php echo external('http://google.com'); ?>` then handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This will show how to implement it using a database and keep a track of the count. There are numerous ways to do it however.

Try this.

http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/qt/track_links.htm

And

http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-track-outbound-links-php

Hope that helps.